# HTML Form Button CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I have the following code (there is other stuff in the form but not relevant):

```
<fieldset>
<form> 
<div><input type="submit" value="Sign Register"></input></div> 
</form>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="viewcurrent.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="View Register"></INPUT></br>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Both buttons work fine. But on the web page they appear underneath each other. What is the correct way to have these buttons next to each other instead of underneath eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way would be to use `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

This would do it:

```
form, form div {
    display:inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ww5vrhtp/)**

You need to change the form and div from block elements to either inline, or inline-block elements.